# Continuously changing Big Data and C#

Tags: database, azure, google-cloud-datastore, azure-table-storage

I have a dataset with {A LOT OF} rows containing continuously correcting data of 50000 assets of 150 customers for well over a decade and a half.

I want to achieve the following:

- Storing data and changing data should be done at a reasonable speed
- Getting data must be super fast
- The customer should be able to retrieve data of day/month/quarter/annual time range for up to 10000 assets at a time

All I need is the best way to implement a data storage solution for this dataset.

I have tried SQL Server - it's slow; Azure Table storage getting data for 10K assets results in 10K queries .. so no good.
Google big data have the same problem.

Any help appreciated

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I need a guide or a reference to work with a read-intensive dataset.